# Difference between the end of file and a byte value of -1 in Java?

Tags: java, inputstream

In java, bytes are signed (-128 to 127), this means an input stream may read a -1 without reaching the end of the file.

So how would a programmer know whether the -1 returned by an input stream indicates end of file or an actual byte value of -1 ?

Comment: [Nope](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()). "_The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255._".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When reading from an `InputStream`, [the `read` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) doesn't return a `byte`; it returns an `int`.

> The value byte is returned as an `int` in the range `0` to `255`. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value `-1` is returned.

Even though bytes are signed in Java, that doesn't matter here, because the byte that is read gets converted to an `int` that can store values above 127.  It also means that `-1` for reaching the end of the stream won't get confused with a value of 255 that is read from the stream.

Once you have the value, you can always cast the `int` to a `byte` to get a byte in the range of -128 to 127, which would convert the 255 to -1.